# (Java Minecraft 1.13) What is the max and min elytra glide speed with rockets?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm planning on creating an item which when held in the off hand while flying gives the player a constant velocity, like a rocket but passive. To know what I need to multiply the players Motion[], by, I need to know approximately what the max flying speed with the rocket is. I checked the wiki but couldn't find any actual numbers, just that it goes faster than without. I also could use the minimum speed required to stay airborne while flying straight/level with the horizon. I've tried using a repeat command block chain for chatting my position while flying but the numbers don't really make any sense, as they dip and spike a lot, so I'm just wondering if there's a way to get these values non experimentally.

Comment: [Related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/332471/how-to-tell-how-fast-im-going-in-sidebar-in-vanilla-minecraft?rq=1) but I don't know if it's exactly duplicate.

Comment: Yeah I saw that one and setup something similar but chatting it and it was very buggy. Maybe tellraw was messing things up? I'll try the scoreboard later to look in real time but I was hoping for a function or value not just from experimenting.

Comment: I wouldn't say this question is a dupe of the linked one, but I would say that you can use the linked answer in order to answer this question.

Comment: Elytra flight is a combination of client and server controlled movement, that's probably why you get bad results when checking the exact momentum. Have you tried getting the position instead and calculating the momentum based on that? Also, couldn't you just let the players boost themselves by giving them an infinite supply of rockets?

Comment: Would something like this maybe work for you? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348832/minecraft-arrow-speed-initial-velocity/348847#348847

Comment: My goal was to allow them to fly without using rockets so they could be using their main hand with, say, a bow, or a custom machine-gun type item I'm making. Also, @FabianRöling I think I saw an answer you gave about the acceleration on a player who's flying, and I did try the Pos[] method but it also spikes a lot. I think I'm going to trial and error the value to see what the best approximation is to get a constant velocity.

Comment: Searching for "eyltra user:me" gives nothing regarding speed. It was probably in a comment, I vaguely remember discussing something like this, but it was flying through the Nether, so not at top speed all the time.

Comment: I think it was creative flying, and what the acceleration is before hitting top speed. The question had the word flying with no elytra mentioned. Maybe it was someone else and I misremembered. Edit: Here it is: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327830/what-is-the-player-acceleration-in-minecraft-when-flying